# Show a file in folder hierarchy

Tags: pycharm, sublimetext

[image]

Is there a button(package or keyboard shortcut) in sublime text like in Pycharm? When click on this button will show where is active file in left menu.
[image]

Comment: And do you have a question?

Comment: @Pileborg Is there such functional in sublime text?

Answer (score -1):

In Sublime Text 3, it *does* highlight the selected file.

[image]

You can get Sublime Text 3 [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).

Comment: You really should note that the folder (or one of its parents) must be included in the project by being dragged and dropped onto the sidebar. It won't just automatically show the contents of a random folder from which you've opened a file.

Comment: @DominatorX seems like you did not understand what i want. Added a gif.