# Defining default scope for 'Find in Path' (PyCharm)

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.4 and I'd like to set a default option for the scope of 'Find in Path'.

Currently, pressing Ctrl-Shift-F (the 'Find in Path' command) pops a window with 'All projects' selected, and I'd like to have 'Directory' with a custom directory set as the default instead. Here's a picture:

[image]

I searched the Settings for anything like this, but could not find it. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**: I've recently discovered that by right-clicking on my project folder and selecting "Find in Path ..." (I mean actually **clicking** the option), the scope is automatically set for the project directory! Strangely enough, the keyboard shortcut indicated in the drop-down menu from right-clicking the project folder is exactly the same as I use. Using the shortcut, however, yields the 'All projects' selection for Scope...

In any case, I still wish to set a default directory for the Find in Path dialog - preferably one that is consistently used regardless of how the dialog was invoked (shortcut, clicking drop-down option).

Comment: I thought it was ok to ask since neither is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724397/configuring-pycharm-to-exit-nest), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625481/pycharm-community-edition-4-5-4-sql-syntax-highlighting), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674538/how-to-run-a-python-file-py-from-the-windows-command-line-without-having-to-t), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653077/pycharm-adding-new-project-interpreter-makes-duplicate), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612581/show-a-file-in-folder-hierarchy), and they were all ok, it seems.

Comment: Not to mention there's a question almost exactly like this with 119 upvotes in the sidebar.

Comment: The existence of off-topic questions is, as per the guidelines, not to be used as a justification for more off-topic questions. However I think this question is OK, since "programmers tools" questions _are_ on-topic. If you want to add voting commentary though, please add that to the comments - it does not belong in questions. (The reason for this is most readers are not voters and any discussion about voting is just a distraction for them).

Comment: Does PyCharm allow custom plugins to be used? If so, perhaps there is a way you can configure a button to open the search dialogue and insert the default value?

Comment: @akalikin: You're wrong. IDE questions are on topic here, as they are *tools commonly used by programmers*. In fact, they're almost *exclusively* used by programmers, AFAICT. See the [help].

Comment: @KenWhite real programmers don't use IDEs, they use [butterfly wings](https://xkcd.com/378/).

Comment: @Yakk You mean universal constants?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems this is the default behavior for the Intellij-like IDEs such as Pycharm.

As answered by the JetBrains support:

> "We have related issue in YouTrack:
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87037 Feel free to vote for
>   it and leave comments."

I reproduce the text of the issue below, in case the link goes dead:

> **IDEA-87037 Usability: Find in Path -- NOT in Whole project**
>
> What steps will reproduce the problem?
>   1. Press Shift-Ctrl-F
>
> What is the expected result? The dialog comes up with the previously
>   selected Scope.
>
> What happens instead? The dialog always comes up with "Whole project"
>   selected.
>
> After having selected "Directory" for the 257th time (and forgetting
>   it one out of four times) I can't help thinking that this is really
>   stupid and obnoxious software.
>
> I want to search in the entire project maybe once out of 100 times.
>   Why does PhpStorm keep insisting that I should search in the whole
>   project?